# Custom chart plugin for SonarQube

Tags: csv, charts, sonarqube

Does anyone know if there is a way to display a custom chart in a SonarQube widget ? I've taken a look at the [SonarQube plugins page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library) but I haven't found anything allowing to do that.

I would like to import a .csv file generated programmatically after each build of my project, and display the different data series it contains into SonarQube.

Something equivalent to the [Jenkins Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) would be perfect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop your own SonarQube plugin for that. Please check [the extension guide](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extension+Guide).